# Can I use Angular.js as templating engine?

Tags: angularjs

I want to generate static html using Angular 1 directives for various use cases. For example:

```
<div>
    Name: <span ng-bind="name"></span>
</div>
<div ng-if="phone">
    Phone: <span ng-bind="phone"></span>
</div>
```

given `{name: "John"}` as `$scope` should generate the following html:

```
<div>
    Name: <span>John</span>
</div>
```

Notice the absence of angular directives and angular ng-if comments. Is something like this possible with Angular 1?

**UPDATE:** I want to use angular's template engine to generate static, non-interactive, html. Think underscore templates or server side template engines. The use case is to generate pieces of html that user can take away into his own non-angular application. Another use case would be to assemble a static html email from an angular template. All of this done without server side. Angular already let's you do this but it leaves all of its artifacts in the html which are obviously not needed for my use case. This is not inefficient as some commenters have said, this is actually quite efficient to be able to generate html without server side and utilizing the already powerful template engine of angular.

Comment: @charlietfl actually, that's not correct. he wants to do something like server side rendering, but at that point you lose the benefits angular gives you, so it seems pretty silly.

Comment: angular runs in browser so really not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm trying to generate static html on client side without using a server. The use case is user fills up a form and in return gets html (think embed code), that he can copy, that shows his data in a presentable format. That is correct, use it as a server side rendering engine. I am completely aware that I'm losing the benefits of angular dynamic nature, hence I said static html. But I am leveraging angular's powerful directives to generate html that I need.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And yes, it is highly inefficient. And you lose the valuable feature of other templating engines that can be rendered on both client and server side (and not limited to JS on server side).

Comment: Please read my update for clarification of use case. How is it inefficient? What other templating engines are you talking about?

Comment: contrary to your assertion, this **is EXTREMELY** inefficient.  There are only two possible ways to accomplish what you want;  A) Allow angular to generate the HTML, then use jQlite (or jQuery) DOM methods to "strip" all the unnecessary attributes (requires extensive knowledge of DOM manipulation and possible angular attributes);  or B)  have a directive that uses jQ DOM functions to manually build the DOM tree.  Either one of these are relying on another framework to manipulate the DOM, since the entire point of the angular framework is avoiding the DOM directly unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Claies, of course it is inefficient when you have to go through all of what you described and that is why I am not doing it and why this question is here. The question is whether it can be done in angular "natively" like you could with underscore templates for example. Of course if it can't be done natively no one in their right mind is going to strip all angular attributes manually. It's just a pity that having such power templating engine we can't utilize it in this way, which means we have to resort to server processing or use something like underscore templates. Cheers.

Comment: Just remove all Angular namespaced attributes (starting with `ng`), what is the big problem?

Comment: @GentiSaliu, I guess this is fine if we only use ng directives. But then you also have to strip all class names, all comments and who knows what else.

Comment: but that's the point, Angular isn't a *templating engine*.  It is a data binding framework.  removing all the angular artifacts breaks the two way binding nature of the framework.  Even "one time bindings" keep track of angular, if only to ensure that they really don't update more than once.  This is not something angular was ever designed for at all.  It *might* be something you can suggest as an enhancement to Angular2, but it is unlikely at this point Angular1 will ever be redesigned for this kind of feature.

Comment: @Claies, yes, I completely understand that. It's just that second time this year I had a real use case for this and could not do it. I do use angular quite a lot in the manner it was designed for. Thank you for the effort and conversation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular was not designed to do this because it is not a templating engine, it is much more than that.

There is no build-in way to accomplish this. Your best bet would be strip all `ng` attributes, angular classes and angular comments and probably some elements too. I personally wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

No. Angular is developed to work on the Client-side. Hence, you cannot use it on the Server-side for templating.

Instead you could try [ejs - embedded js](http://ejs.co/) for templating. That is much more simpler and serves as a templating engine.

Check out [EJS Website](http://ejs.co/)